# How can I retrieve the value of a PASTE (copy-pasta) event in a GWT TextBox?

Tags: java, events, gwt, textbox, copy-paste

Hello fellow SO members,

I want to prevent the user from copy-pasting values in my TextBox IF AND ONLY IF the values do not respect a certain condition.

For instance, I created a DigitsOnlyTextBox which will be used for phone numbers.
I already made it so only `Character.isDigit` characters can be typed into the box, and the user cannot copy-paste values into it, using :

```
this.sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
```

and

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);

    // Permet d'empêcher le copier-coller, donc d'entrer des caractères non-numériques

    if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONPASTE) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

But I'd like to verify if the copy-pasted String is "digits only" and if so, let the event happen (therefore the text added).

tl;dr :
see title

Thank you for your time.
Sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste):

> There is currently no DOM-only way to obtain the text being pasted

IMO, you'd better let the "paste" happen and then "rewrite" the textbox's value to strip non-numerics (actually, I'd even rather do it onValueChange only) or simply flag the box as invalid when its value isn't numeric-only (this is what IntegerBox does for instance).

Comment: "no DOM-ONLY way"
Does this mean there's another way?
But yeah, I agree with you, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Just save the old value in a local variable and right after the event you excecute your logic and if the value is not ok just keep the old text.

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
{
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    final String oldValue = getValue();
    switch (event.getTypeInt())
    {
        case Event.ONPASTE:
            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand()
            {

                @Override
                public void execute()
                {
                    if(<not ok>)
                       setValue(oldValue);
                }

            });
            break;
    }
}
```